# NSD equivalent in android API level <16

Tags: java, android, api, networking

As most of us know the android `NSD` (Network Service Discovery) framework has made networking very simple and easy in Local networks. However the android APIs for the `NSD implementation` start from API level 16 (Jelly Bean). I am concerned with LAN rather than the internet

So is there a simple way like the NSD in lower API levels (*Gingerbread and ICS*).
More clearly speaking what's optimum way to implement network services in application for `API level <16`

Comment: I think so, you can use the socket apis from Java.net package

Comment: Refer to the answer in this LInk :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007372/android-network-discovery-service-ish-before-api-14

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JmDNS Java Library.

[JmDNS Library](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/)

[Tutorial to use in Android](http://home.heeere.com/tech-androidjmdns.html)